# Django Templates: How to detect a request method?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I would like the next template works:

```
{% if not form.errors and request.method == 'POST' %}

    <span id='saved'>Data has stored.</span>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        setTimeout( function() { $( '#saved' ).fadeOut( 'slow' ); }, 2000 );
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

How can I get the access to request.method within a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) should do that for you.